# React Redux cannot access props from method in onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-proptypes

I have the following for my index.js. I have set up React with create-react-app. I then installed redux and react redux.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppContainer from './AppContainer';
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

const defaultState = {
    activeTab: 'firstTab'
};

const reducer = function(state=defaultState, action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TAB_CHANGED':
            return state.merge({
                activeTab: state.activeTab
            })
        default: return state;
    }
};
const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and the following for my AppContainer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
      activeTab: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  doSomething = function(){
      this.props.dispatch('TAB_CHANGED', {activeTab: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">{ this.props.activeTab }</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
            <button onClick={this.doSomething}>Do Something</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return state;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppContainer);
```

The page loads fine when first rendered. The react dom can access the `this.props.activeTab`. however when I click on the `Do Something` button I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind the **doSomething** function to the context of the component else it this will refer to the context of the render. So add the snippet to the constructor

```
constructor(){
    super()
    this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
}
```

**or** ES6 - declare doSomething as an arrow function and there will be no need for bind in the constructor

```
constructor(){}
doSomething = () => {
....
}
```